# DIY: Multi-Panel Sliding Chalkboard

Tags: interior, materials

I have three chalkboards that I purchased from Amazon right [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071ZRT2Z6).
Each board is roughly 10 lbs. I want to DIY a railing system that can hold all three boards such that

1. Two of the boards are fixed and mounted side-by-side; these are the inner boards
2. The third board is able to slide horizontally; this is the outer board

Of course, I want something that can support 30 lbs. Something like the following, but less bulky and only the outer layer is allowed to slide:

[image]

Does anyone know what kind of rails I should buy and what kind of wheels? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the kits for hanging closet doors like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-48-in-Steel-Sliding-Door-Set-18396/202041870) (an example, not an endorsement).  The rail across the top also hides the track and the wheels that ride up inside it.  At the bottom, you put a fixed guide that the panel slides through.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a page from sliding windows and doors.  All you need is one track—the back two panels can be affixed directly to the wall.  Mount the track at the bottom and top, and slip the moving blackboard up into the top track and let it drop into the bottom track.